# base64 decode output has non-ascii characters

Tags: python, base64, decode, non-ascii-characters

I am having trouble properly decoding base64 data. It decodes the message properly, but also includes a ton of non-ascii characters which then I have to clean as well, so I was wondering if I was decoding it incorrectly or if I will need to create a script to clean the text post decoding. Below is the python code and part of the output I am getting to illustrate. Thanks!

```
message= base64.b64decode(base64_message).decode(errors='ignore')
```

[image]

Comment: You could clean it in a few ways. Assuming `s` is your string: `print(''.join([c for c in s if ord(c) < 128]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're obviously trying to decode a `Word` document, which is by definition not plain text at all. Make sure what you're trying to decode is text. Otherwise save the decoding result to a file (`file.docx`?) and open it in the appropriate application.

---

Following up your question in the comments, you don't have to get the text from base64, leave it as it is and write to the file. Instead of

```
base64.b64decode(base64_message).decode(errors='ignore')
```

use just

```
base64.b64decode(base64_message)
```

and everything will be fine:

```
>>> a = base64.b64encode('\x01\x02\x04')
>>> a
'AQIE'
>>> base64.b64decode(a)
'\x01\x02\x04'
```

Comment: Thanks. You are correct, these are word documents. I tried writing the output of the code above to a docx  but got the following error: ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters. I tried encoding in ASCII and Decoding in ASCII as well but to no avail. So I guess the question really is, how can I use python to reverse an encoded base 64 docx string